# TypeORM: "No migrations pending" on windows 11

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, windows-11, nestjs-typeorm

I have one `nestjs` app where I'm using `typeorm`, `PostgreSQL` . This app is working fine on linux/mac os. But in windows 11, no data found on migration table, that's why no table is created on PostgreSQL database. When I run `npm run start:dev`, it is showing following message on terminal:

```
$ npm run start:dev
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> service@1.0.0 start:dev
> nest start --watch --preserveWatchOutput

[2:00:24 PM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[2:01:01 PM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

.......................................................................................
.......................................................................................

{"level":30,"ctx":"InstanceLoader","msg":"AppModule dependencies initialized"}
{"level":30,"ctx":"DBLogger","query":"SELECT * FROM current_schema()"}
{"level":30,"ctx":"DBLogger","msg":"No classes were found using the provided glob pattern:  \"dist/src/server/migration/*{.ts,.js}\""}
{"level":30,"ctx":"DBLogger","query":"CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\""}
{"level":30,"ctx":"DBLogger","query":"SELECT version();"}
{"level":30,"ctx":"DBLogger","query":"SELECT * FROM \"information_schema\".\"tables\" WHERE \"table_schema\" = 'public' AND \"table_name\" = 'migrations'"}
{"level":30,"ctx":"DBLogger","query":"SELECT * FROM \"migrations\" \"migrations\" ORDER BY \"id\" DESC","parameters":[]}
{"level":30,"ctx":"DBLogger","msg":"No migrations are pending"}
{"level":30,"ctx":"InstanceLoader","msg":"TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized"}

.......................................................................................
.......................................................................................

{"level":30,"ctx":"NestApplication","msg":"Nest application successfully started"}
```

I have build by running`npm run build`. Then run `npm run typeorm -- migration:run`

```
npm run typeorm -- migration:run
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> service@1.0.0 typeorm
> typeorm-ts-node-esm -d ./ormconfig.ts "migration:run"

query: SELECT * FROM current_schema()
query: SELECT version();
query: SELECT * FROM "information_schema"."tables" WHERE "table_schema" = 'public' AND "table_name" = 'migrations'
query: SELECT * FROM "migrations" "migrations" ORDER BY "id" DESC
No migrations are pending
```

**ormconfig.ts**  code:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

dotenv.config();

const connection = new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres' as const,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'mango',
  database: 'loyalty',
  entities: ['src/server/entity/*.{ts,js}'],
  migrations: ['src/server/migration/*.{ts,js}'],
  extra: {
    ssl: false,
  },
});

export default connection;
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          imports: [ConfigModule],
          inject: [ConfigService],
          useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
            return {
              type: 'postgres',
              entities: [],
              synchronize: false,
              migrations: ['dist/src/server/migration/*{.ts,.js}'],
              migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
              migrationsRun: true,
            };
          },
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private connection: Connection) {}
}
```

File structure:

```
project
|--------> dist
              |--------> src
                         |--------> server
                                         |---------> migration
|--------> src
     |--------> server
                     |---------> migration
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** I also run this project inside Docker container, and still same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["No migrations pending" when attempting to run migrations , used to work with no problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75501423/no-migrations-pending-when-attempting-to-run-migrations-used-to-work-with-no)

Comment: Nope, it is not working, as you might see in my code, I already added those field.

Comment: how about ormconfig.ts file?

Answer (score 2):

The solution: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9766

It seems the `glob` dependency from `typeorm@0.3.12` is not working correctly with Windows.

Comment: yup, you are right, it is glob dependency issue.